# Add some primitive shape to the mesh in JavaFX 8

Tags: 3d, mesh, javafx-8

I wonder, if it's possible to add some shape, for example - Sphere, to my Mesh in MeshView.
So, I have three arrays with points, texCoords and faces, and due to these arrays I have a Mesh in MeshView. Everything works great. But how can I add something to this Mesh. I have such code:

```
meshView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if (mouseEvent.isControlDown()) {
                PickResult pickResult = mouseEvent.getPickResult();
                Point3D point = pickResult.getIntersectedPoint();
                if (DEBUG) {
                    System.out.println("X=" + point.getX() + "; Y=" + point.getY() + "; Z=" + point.getZ());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And so, now I want to mark this selected Point3D with small sphere of the other color. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to add things to my Mesh I load an STL using the STL loader from http://www.interactivemesh.org/.  I add the newly loaded mesh to my 3D world.  I then save the two meshes into a combined STL.  I am using the saving code from toxiclibs.  I can't post the link because I don't have enough reputation.  Just search for toxiclibs STLWriter source.  I rewrote it so that it would fit in with Java 8

My app can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7trj4vq5bq8fm4y/38JMFqHlCs
I wrote it to control a DLP 3D printer.  It uses the latest JavaFX 8.  It shows 3D objects.  You can create supports for the 3D objects (same idea as what you have).  You can move the objects around.  It saves.  It uses the JavaFX 8 webbrowser that allows you to download 3D objects and add them to the 3D world automatically.  It also has a library browser so that you can see a 3D preview of each object in your library and when you double click on the row it changes it so that it is true 3D and you can move the things around and turn them around on the row.  Still probably a month worth of coding until I will be happy with it.